# How to sync my Kindle with my Kindle library without using WiFi?

Tags: kindle, send-to-kindle, 3g, wifi

This is a question that plagued me a while ago when my wireless router refused to work correctly with my Kindle Touch (3G edition).

I had a document that I wanted to transfer to my Kindle as well as my Kindle Library. Both of these tasks where easy enough to accomplish on their own:

- I connected my Kindle to my PC via USB and copied it to the appropriate directory on the device.
- I sent an email to my send-to-Kindle email address with the document as an attachment.

Unfortunately, when my Kindle would sync via 3G, I would end up with an extra "book" in my library - the document I sent to my library via email. Of course, the document wouldn't download since I wasn't connected via WiFi so I was left with a copy of the document on the device and another copy waiting to download.

Why couldn't my Kindle recognize that I *already had the document* on the device? Is there any way to add a document / book to your Kindle library and still have the Kindle recognize that it exists when manually copied to the device?

Comment: The document should appear automatically if you copied it to the correct folder and it is in a compatible format. Maybe try following the instructions on the [Amazon website](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201242130).

Answer (score 1):

Using Calibre you could try :

- Adding the book in the Calibre library
- Sending the book to your Amazon email address (Right click on the book > Connect / Share)
- Sending the book to your Kindle while it is connected to your computer (Right click on the book > Send to device)

Of course this requires some initial configuration (telling Calibre how to send email, ...) and I can not guarantee it will work having no 3G Kindle to test it myself.

But it seems to be worth a try as it would most likely make sure that the file that gets copied on your kindle has the right format/information to be identified correctly.