# How to put downloaded Kindle e-books on to a Kindle device that cannot access the internet

Tags: kindle, download

I have a Kindle device, but it cannot connect to the internet because the only internet I can access requires signing in, and the Kindle just can't be controlled accurately enough for me to select the User Name and Password fields to type in.

The Kindle itself is also registered with some Amazon account whose details I don't have. I have my own Amazon account, and I have purchased an e-book on it. I have also downloaded it from the Cloud on to the Kindle app for PC, and downloaded it (apparently on to my hard drive) from the Kindle app. So the book should be sitting somewhere on my PC.

Is it possible for me to transfer the book file from my PC to my Kindle over USB? How do I even locate the book document on my PC?

Or, to circumvent this problem, if anyone knows how to navigate sign-in screens on a non-touch-screen Kindle, that would make everything a lot easier.

(Note: I can read the book on my PC with no problems, but I'd much rather read it on the Kindle.)

Comment: Very similar question: https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/45/how-to-sync-my-kindle-with-my-kindle-library-without-using-wifi Unfortunately in your case, the Kindle is registered with a different account than the one you purchased the book with.

Answer (score 2):

Calibre can transfer the book from your PC to Kindle.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned the Kindle is linked to an Amazon account. You should know the password to re-link to another Amazon account.

I don't think you can load books bought from one account to another, directly.
But it's possible to use Kindle books as gift. So, you'll be buying the book in your account and gift it to another user. Again, to access the book you should have the password.

There is another option to add second user with your Kindle. You can add second account under Kindle's user settings.